# ¿Cómo filtrar en un JSON por determinadas propiedades o todas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, filtro

Tengo un array de objetos o JSON el cual sé filtrar en JavaScript por alguna (una sola) propiedad, el array es así:

```
var productos = [
    {id: 1, nombreProducto: 'Papas BBQ', precio: 1700},
    {id: 2, nombreProducto: 'Gaseosa x 1', precio: 2500},
    {id: 3, nombreProducto: 'Arroz Libra', precio: 1700},
    {id: 4, nombreProducto: 'Chupeta', precio: 500},
    {id: 5, nombreProducto: 'Postre Y', precio: 5000},
    {id: 6, nombreProducto: 'Carne Libra', precio: 15000},
];
```

Generalmente lo he filtrado así:

```
var coincidencias = productos.filter(producto => producto.nombreProducto.includes('G'));
```

Pero ¿cómo hacerlo con todas o algunas de las propiedades que este JSON contenga?
Mi objetivo es crear un campo tipo buscador en donde según lo que el usuario escriba le devuelva las coincidencias del array con todas las propiedades.

Comment: Puedes crear tu mismo una funcion y darselo a filter, Arreglo.filter( (objeto) => FiltrarPropiedades(objeto));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues se puede hacer con un filter y despues con `Object.values(objeto)` tienes todos los valores del objeto en un array, despues ya luego solo tienes que buscar si alguno incluye tu cadena de búsqueda y listo.

```
function filtrarProductos(array, searchString){
   const result = array.filter(x => {
        const values = Object.values(x);
        if (values.some(y => y.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()))){
           return x;
        }
   })
   return result;
}


console.log(filtrarProductos(productos, "500"));
```

El resultado sería:

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "nombreProducto": "Gaseosa x 1",
    "precio": 2500
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "nombreProducto": "Chupeta",
    "precio": 500
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "nombreProducto": "Postre Y",
    "precio": 5000
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "nombreProducto": "Carne Libra",
    "precio": 15000
}
]
```

Comment: Si busco los productos con precio "1" me va a traer todos los que tengan un 1 en el precio, y ademas me va a devolver el que tiene id "1", y tambien me devolveria el que se llama "Gaseosa x 1". La funcion deberia recibir otro parametro con la propiedad sobre la que hay que realizar la busqueda para que esto no suceda.

Comment: No es evitar que eso suceda.  Lo hice como tu pusiste, haberlo explicado mejor

Comment: No entiendo, yo que puse?

Comment: Perdona, pensé que eras el que puso la pregunta..... eso me pasa por no revisar bien jejejeej

Comment: perdona vos, tenes razon jaja, el usuario pidio exactamente lo que vos hiciste. Ahora veo el ultimo parrafo y lo aclara. Mala mia.

Comment: Perfecto, lo probé y era lo que estaba necesitando, como especifique; planteé la pregunta de esa manera ya que quiero que ya sea con el precio, con el nombre del producto o cualquier otro parámetro, muestre las respectivas coincidencias. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var productos = [
    {id: 1, nombreProducto: 'Papas BBQ', precio: 1700},
    {id: 2, nombreProducto: 'Gaseosa x 1', precio: 2500},
    {id: 3, nombreProducto: 'Arroz Libra', precio: 1700},
    {id: 4, nombreProducto: 'Chupeta', precio: 500},
    {id: 5, nombreProducto: 'Postre Y', precio: 5000},
    {id: 6, nombreProducto: 'Carne Libra', precio: 15000},
];

const buscar = (array,propiedad, query) => {
 const q = query.toString().toLowerCase();
 return array.filter(element => element[propiedad].toString().toLowerCase().includes(query))
}

console.log(buscar(productos, "nombreProducto", "postre"))
console.log(buscar(productos, "id", 3))
console.log(buscar(productos, "precio", 1700))
```

Podes hacer una función `buscar` que recibe como argumento un `array` *(donde va a buscar)*, una `propiedad` *(tiene que ser una cadena de texto con la propiedad sobre la que querés buscar. Podría seleccionarse desde un select)* y una `query` *(la cadena o numero que vas a buscar)*

Primero, al parámetro `query` lo transformo en una cadena de texto, ya que la función `includes` es solo para buscar strings, y si no hago esto no podrías buscar precios o ids. También la convierto en minúsculas. De esta manera es lo mismo buscar "Postre" o "postre".

Luego retorno un `filter` para acceder a cada elemento, en la propiedad que le pasamos por parámetro (con `element[nombreDeLaPropiedad]` podes acceder a una propiedad teniendo su nombre en un string, como en este caso, es lo mismo que hacer `element.precio`, si el parametro recibido fuera "precio". Acá podes leer más al respecto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Una vez que accede a cada elemento, transforma su valor en `string` y la paso a minusculas exactamente igual que hago con la query.

Espero te sirva, saludos.